# Increasing Python table font in Jupyter

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-table

Upon trying to increase the size of a Matplotlib table generated from a csv file, the following code will not work to enlarge the font of the table's text:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8,5.5)
```

How can I increase the size of the font in Jupyter?

Comment: If you want a more precise answer, you'll have to provide a little more code context.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
   
header = ["header" for i in range(5)] 
values = [["{}".format(c) for c in range(5)] for r in range(5)] 
   
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.set_axis_off() 
table = ax.table( 
    cellText = values,  
    rowLabels = header,  
    colLabels = header, 
    cellLoc ='center',  
    loc ='upper left')  

# this let you set the font
table.set_fontsize(15)  
# the table doesn't scale with the font, you'll have to enlarge it manually
table.scale(1.5, 1.5)     
   
ax.set_title('Example') 
   
plt.show()
```

Comment: the csv data has many rows and wide columns and even with table.set_fontsize, the table value font sizes seem to stay small. is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Please provide an example of how you create the table

Comment: table = ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')

Comment: The font doesn’t change at all if you increment the value in `set_fontsize`?